# Cannot use ControlParameters in ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource

I am trying to make a simple CRUD using a ListView and a ObjectDataSource in ASP.NET Web Forms. I cannot use ControlParameters in my ObjectDataSource to insert data.

Here is how my ObjectDataSource is defined in the aspx file.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" 
        runat="server"
        TypeName="BookModel"
        InsertMethod="AddBook"
        UpdateMethod="EditBook"
        DeleteMethod="DeleteBook"
        SelectMethod="GetAllBooks">
        <InsertParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="BookName" ControlID="form1$BookName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="AuthorID" ControlID="form1$AuthorID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="SubjectID" ControlID="form1$SubjectID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="Copies" ControlID="form1$Copies" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Here is my ListView.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1"
    runat="server"
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1"
    InsertItemPosition="LastItem"
    DataKeyNames="BookID"
    >

    <ItemTemplate>

        <%# Eval("BookID") %>,
        <%# Eval("BookName") %>,
        <%# Eval("AuthorID") %>,
        <%# Eval("SubjectID") %>,
        <%# Eval("Copies") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" runat="server" />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>



    <InsertItemTemplate>

        <br />
        Book name: <asp:TextBox ID="BookName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("BookName") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
        Subject: <asp:TextBox ID="SubjectID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SubjectID") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
        Author: <asp:TextBox ID="AuthorID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("AuthorID") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
        Copies: <asp:TextBox ID="Copies" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Copies") %>'></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Add" CommandName="Insert" />

    </InsertItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

Whenever I run my application and try to insert a new record, I get this error

**Could not find control 'form1$BookName' in ControlParameter 'BookName'.**

My ListView and ObjectDataSource are enclosed in the same form and that form has id form1.

Answer (score 0):

I removed InsertParameters from my ObjectDataSource definition.

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" 
    runat="server"
    TypeName="BookModel"
    InsertMethod="AddBook"
    UpdateMethod="EditBook"
    DeleteMethod="DeleteBook"
    SelectMethod="GetAllBooks">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```